# findAttribute("value") returns null in firefox

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, firefox, automation

element
                                                                            .getAttribute("value") works fine in chrome and returns value but same method I am trying to use in firefox and its returning "null" value

```
<textarea id="xyz" class="span12 ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-maxlength" name="otherDescription" data-ng-model="other.description" data-ng-required="true" placeholder="Enter trip details" type="text" maxlength="10000" required="required"/>
```

Comment: are you using Firefox driver?

Comment: Share `HTML` as well as your tried code.

Comment: .getFirstTripDetaisInput()
                                                                            .getAttribute("value")
                                                                            .contains(xyz));
<textarea id="xyz" class="span12 ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-maxlength" name="otherDescription" data-ng-model="other.description" data-ng-required="true" placeholder="Enter trip details" type="text" maxlength="10000" required="required"/>

Answer (score 0):

Check out if your input tag has value attribute in firefox else try with gettext() some times this pattern changes from browser to browser.

If the above option is not working,you can go for the below

JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@itemprop='telephone']"));
jse.executeScript("return arguments[0].innerhtml", element);

Comment: in my assertin I am velidating value that I have entered, iput contains same valuse, usinig javascript how can I validate that?

Comment: Get the text to a string as copied below and input it to your assertion               WebElement currentTimeElement=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='ytp-time-current']"));
String content=(String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML", currentTimeElement);